# Pass function name as one of the positional arguments in a script

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash function `bar` that takes a function `foo` as an argument but have `foo` also take parameters.

```
function foo() {
    foo_args=("$@")
    for i in "${foo_args[@]}";
        do
            echo "$i"
        done
}

function bar() {
        ($1) 
}

foo_args=(
        "one" "two" "three"
)

bar foo foo_args
```

How do I pass `foo_args` to `bar`?

EDIT:

I tried:

```
bar foo "${foo_args[@]}"
```

With:

```
function bar() {
        params="${3}"
        ($1 ${params[@]}) 
}
```

But `foo` only looks at the first element.

Comment: What is your purpose of this code? Your `bar()` function has no meaning at all. Also your `foo()` function never gets invoked

Comment: My bar function is a function called `action_needed`, and `foo` is any action that actually performs something. `foo`'s arguments are what `foo` acts on. There might be many actions needed, but they all have the same warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *not* quite sure what you are intending to do with your `foo()` and `bar()` functions, but in the function `bar` you are not receiving the entire positional arguments, but just `$1`, use `$@` instead. I've modified the code to suit your requirements assuming you need to pass the arguments from `bar()` to `foo()`. Since your first argument contains the function name get it in `$1` and use `shift` to drop `$1` and have rest of the arguments under `$@`

Also drop the non-standard `function` keyword from the function definition. It is perfectly OK to not mention it

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo() {
    foo_args=("$@")
    for arg in "${foo_args[@]}"; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}

bar() {
    function=$1; shift

    [ "$(type -t "$function")" = function ] || 
        { echo "$function prototype is not available" >&2; return 1 ; }

    "$function" "$@"
}

foo_args=(
    "one" "two" "three"
)

bar foo "${foo_args[@]}"
```

Also it is safe to check using `type -t` to ensure the prototype for the function invoked exists and throw an error message if not.